# Can I remove the limit of number of languages in Google Search results?

Tags: google-search, localization

I see I can select only eight languages for Google Search results.

Is it possible to do a search in all languages?

Answer (score 1):

Google already searches all languages by default:

[image]

Comment: Strange, I see the contrary:

Comment: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2eG2z.png" width="100" height="100">

Comment: I see ![enter image description here][3]
  [3]: http://i.imgur.com/2eG2z.png

Comment: But doesn't the dropdown for "Quelle language" have an option for "toutes languages"?

Comment: @notbob Not related to the question above; to add links in the comments, use the following schema: `[see_this_link](http://the_actual_link/)`

Comment: nope, 125 languages listed including klingon and pirate, but no option to include all.

Comment: @notbob What's the URL of the page in [this image](http://i.imgur.com/2eG2z.png) you linked to? Also, try going to this page: http://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en and let us know what you see (should be the same as the page in the screenshot I put in my answer above).